# Create an email account via Telnet

Tags: email, telnet

I know how to telnet into a smtp server in order to send emails and 
I know how to telnet into a pop server in order to read emails.

Is there some protocol I can telnet into to create user accounts?

Comment: Not sure why I'm being downvoted. Is this somehow a poor question? I read an RFC for SMTP and skimmed through an RFC for POP and did not find anything for creating user accounts. I assumed that there might be some other protocol that is used for that, but I could not find it. The only answer posted so far states that such a protocol does not exist. This is useful information to me. I don't see how this question is bad.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in SMTP command to create a user account / mailbox.

You will have to use the GUI or command line provided.

Otherwise anyone would just telnet / netcat to a machine running an SMTP server and attempt to create mailboxes.